# SQL inserting data into a temp table, splitting a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, temp

I am trying to get data from a table and split the information into two columns in a temp table but I'm having a spot of trouble with it. Let me explain.

```
table : a    
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID  |    Type   |    Word   |     
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |    Fr     |   Wee     |   
|   1   |    Eng    |   Yes     |   
|   2   |    Fr     |   Non     |  
|   2   |    Eng    |   No      |   
|   3   |    Fr     |   Bien    |  
|   3   |    Eng    |   Good    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have the above table and I want to insert the word data into a temp table but I want to split it into French words and English Words. I have used the following.

```
CREATE TABLE #translation
(
French NVARCHAR(50),
English NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #translation (French)
SELECT Word FROM a
WHERE Type = 'Fr'

INSERT INTO #translation (English)
SELECT Word FROM a
WHERE Type = 'Eng'
```

This sort of works but produces:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|  Row  |  French   |  English  |     
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |    Wee    |   NULL    |   
|   2   |    Non    |   NULL    |   
|   3   |    Bien   |   NULL    |  
|   4   |    NULL   |   Yes     |   
|   5   |    NULL   |   No      |  
|   6   |    NULL   |   Good    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Ideally I want them side by side.

Any tips for this?

If more information is needed please ask.

Comment: btw, it's "Oui" not "Wee"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
INSERT INTO #translation (French, English)
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'FR' THEN Word END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'EN' THEN Word END)       
    FROM a
    GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional agggregation:

```
select id, max(case when Type = 'Fr' then word end) as French,
max(case when Type = 'Eng' then word end) as English
from table1
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pivot` to Transpose the rows to columns

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE #ACTUAL(ID INT, Type Varchar(10), Word Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #ACTUAL
SELECT 1,'Fr' ,'Wee'   
UNION ALL    
SELECT 1,'Eng','Yes'       
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Fr' ,'Non'      
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Eng','No'     
UNION ALL  
SELECT 3,'Fr' ,'Bien'   
UNION ALL   
SELECT 3,'Eng','Good'
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM #ACTUAL A
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(Word) FOR Type IN ([Fr],[Eng] )
)PV
```

Result

```
ID  Fr      Eng
----------------
1   Wee     Yes
2   Non     No
3   Bien    Good
```